# Google Calendar Subscription ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, google-calendar-api

I am developing my Web Application on ASP.NET and i am trying to implement Google Calendar version 3 in my application. Recently Google has launched a new feature in Google calendar that any one can subscribe to public calendars or to a specific calendar so can any one please help me how to do this in ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

Just download the appropriate API and call the right methods:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#Calendar_API

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/

Comment: My project is in running mode. Currently i am able to insert/delete/update events on Google calendar, but the problem is that i want to subscribe to other calendars using my application so how can i do this. Like if you log in into Google calendar then click the smart tag of "Other Calendar" then click on "Browse Interesting Calendar" here you will see that we can subscribe to any calendar. So i want to so the same from my application not from Google UI.

Comment: Kindly check the below code for creating of calendar. But here i am specifying the Calendar ID as i know my calendar ID, but if i am going to subscribe any Interesting Calendars Like "United State Holidays" so how can i know the calendar ID of this particular calendar. 
    Calendar cal = new Calendar();
    cal.Summary = GoogleCalendarAppointmentObj.CalendarName;
    Calendar createdcal = CalService.Calendars.Insert(cal).Execute();